# Content Script not injected correctly to nested iframes in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I am developing chrome extension accordingly, one of the requirements is to catch the event listeners that are triggered in the relevant iframe through the content script injected into each iframe. That is when click event occurs in the iframe and I need to get it to the extension. The diagram below shows how the web page related to my iframes exists and how content scripts are injected.

[Iframe Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbLNK.png)

The problem is that I want to get the events in the last frameReports iframe (see above image). Each iframe above has the correct content scripts injected except frameReports. frameReports has only one content script. The relevant content script is not injected so I cannot catch the event triggered in the iframe.

But when I temporarily remove the relevant iframe from the DOM through devtools, all the relevant content scripts injected properly. What is the reason for this? I am using manifest version 2. I’ll include the relevant files below.

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
      "manifest_version": 2,
        "description": "My Extension",
          "background": { },
  "permissions": ["tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "webRequest",
    "<all_urls>",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
  ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "all_frames": true,
          "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file://*/*"],
          "js": ["contentScript.js"],
          "match_about_blank": true
        }
      ],
        "options_ui": {
    "page": "options/options.html"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": ["icons/icon.png"]

}
```

**contentScript.js**

```
document.addEventHandler('click', function (event) {
    if (event.button == 0 && event.isTrusted) {
        var target = event.target;
    // Code goes here
    }
});
```

Comment: You only have 1 content script listed in your example. Also you can add this to matches `"*://*/*"`

Comment: Yes. there are other content scripts. But this is the content scipt that I need to be injected.

Comment: Some iframes cannot run content scripts due to a bug in Chrome. If it's a same-origin iframe then you can access its `contentWindow` directly from your higher content script and add a listener.

Comment: @wOxxOm Does highe content script means the order in which content scipts are defined?. Yes. This is a same-origin frame.

Comment: I also have a another question. Can the iframe stop injecting content scripts? @wOxxOm